# Command + S stops working

Tags: keyboard, catalina, macos

I have a MacBook Air 11-inch early 2015. I recently updated it to Catalina. Everything seems to work fine apart from one annoyance.

For some reason, <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> stops working in all apps. It will work for several hours then stop without warning. (It's happening right now and I've tested it with Sublime, Safari, Terminal and Mail.) To fix it, I have to reboot the laptop.

The <kbd>S</kbd> key on my keyboard is fine, and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> keyboard shortcuts work as expected.

I have no idea at all why <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> doesn't work. Any ideas?

**Update**

It's happened again. It looks like a single app might have been causing it. I've narrowed it down to three possible candidates.

Comment: A genuine hardware problem with the keyboard is unlikely to be fixed by a reboot, and the fact the Command and S work independently also counts against that. Check your installation for third-party software that might be causing problems, particularly background processes. Also, look at the File menu to ensure that the keyboard shortcut is shown next to Save.

Comment: Is it possible hat Cmd-S got remapped to something else?  Check your keyboard settings.   Also try booting into Safe Mode and/or a (new) clean user acct.  See if the problem persists.

Comment: Which three candidates?

Comment: Malwarebytes, BetterSnapTool and IO (Markdown editor). I currently have IO and BetterSnapTool running. I suspect it was Malwarebytes.

Comment: It happened again 5 minutes ago. Quitting IO (Markdown editor) fixed it.